# How do i prevent vscode from breaking my pasted code?

Tags: visual-studio-code

Im not using any plugins for breaking my code, i think it's an integrated function. This problem is now since a few weeks and it's driving me crazy pasting code and then putting every line back.

Here is a screenshot of my code (i just copied this line):
https://i.stack.imgur.com/7t3ZL.jpg

Here is a screenshot of my code (i pasted it):
https://i.stack.imgur.com/kSwPL.jpg

Why is my vscode breaking the lines everytime?
Thanks in advance for your help, i really apreciate it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is the default formatter wrapping text (or trying to) at the default of 80 columns.

If you want to override this, you can do so by adding this line to your settings.json file:

```
"html.format.wrapLineLength": 0
```

If you prefer to change your settings from the GUI instead of the json file, open the command palette and open the settings from there. Once in it, look for "HTML format wrap line length" in the search box and change the value to 0.

You find a shortcut to the settings here too:

[image]